# Dynamic path for django FileSystemStorage

Tags: python, django, django-models, filefield

I was trying to save some files using Django FileSystemStorage. My model is as shown below

```
key_store = FileSystemStorage(
location='account/files/'+datetime.date.today().isoformat())


class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='auth_user_account_relation')
    subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    info_file = models.FileField(storage=key_store)
```

But when I save an object of this model only the file name is stored in the db.

So when I try to access the path it returns path appended with todays date and not as the uploaded date. 
ie. If I upload a file on say 09-21-2015 and I try to access the path on the next day it will return 
`account/files/09-22-2015/<file_name>` which will be an invalid path.
So what tweak should be made to store absolute path in db. Or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to use [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) with a callable instead and prefix the date there. Dynamic storage paths also don't play well with migrations.

Comment: for storage i couldn't find an option `upload_to`. I don't want to store those files as media files.(i.e. they are only to use at server side not to be served)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, your version does not do what you intend it to:

```
key_store = FileSystemStorage(
    location='account/files/'+datetime.date.today().isoformat()
)
```

is evaluated when the module is loaded (usually only when you start your application). After that the date stays fixed as long as the module is not re-loaded. Hence it points to a directory with the name of the date the application was started, which is probably not what you want.

Also, `FileSystemStorage` serializes with full path name, meaning that this also triggers a migration every other day (because the storage path changed).

You can solve this problem by using a combination of `FileSystemStorage` (to store files outside of the media directory) and `upload_to` with a callable:

```
key_store = FileSystemStorage(location='account/files/')

def key_store_upload_to(instance, path):
    # prepend date to path
    return os.path.join(
        datetime.date.today().isoformat(), 
        path
    )

class Account(models.Model):
    # [...]
    info_file = models.FileField(storage=key_store, upload_to=key_store_upload_to)
```

This uses a new `FileSystemStorage` for the base directory of uploaded files and `upload_to` to determine the name of an uploaded file relative to the storage's root.

**Edit 1**: Thanks for pointing out that `upload_to` takes a date format.

Since `upload_to` also takes `strftime()` format specifiers, a pure-date related path choice can also be implemented without the callable:

```
info_file = models.FileField(storage=key_store, upload_to='account/files/%Y-%m-%d')
```

As for explanation:

A *storage* is essentially an abstraction of a hierarchical file system in django. `FileField`s always store their files in a *storage*. By default the *media storage* is used, but that can be changed.

To determine the path a file is uploaded to, `FileField` roughly does the following

1. Retrieve the *request path*, which is the path the file was uploaded with.
2. Check if the `upload_to` option specified for the file field.
   If `upload_to` is a string, use this string as a base directory. `upload_to` is run through `strftime()` to process any date specifiers. Concatenate `upload_to` and the request path, which results in a target path relative to the storage.
3. If `upload_to` is a callable, call it with `(instance, request_path)` and use the return value as the target path (relative to the storage).
4. Check if the file already exists within the storage. If so, derive a new, unique path.
5. Save file to the storage with the target path.
6. Store the target path (still relative to storage) inside the database.

As one can see, the storage is meant to be more or less static. Changing the storage potentially invalidates all existing file paths in the database, because they are relative to the storage.

Comment: i haven't tried this yet. still couldn't figure out the reason why we have to manually append the path using `os.path.join`. usually if it is a media storage `upload_to` will take options like `%d-%m-%Y`. Will that work with FileSystemStorage?

Comment: @midhun I'm not sure I understand you correctly. `upload_to` either takes a string pointing to a subdirectory of the storage (which defaults to the media storage) or a *callable* that is called to generate the target path dynamically. You cannot easily change the storage every day (you can but, but just don't). So create a storage pointing to the top directory for all uploaded files and generate the upload path dynamically.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that if we give `info_file = models.FileField(storage=key_store, upload_to='%d-%m-%Y')` the purpose will be served without the need of that callable. I was not aware of the fact that `upload_to` and `storage` can be used together.

Comment: @midhun Ah. I did not even know that `upload_to` takes `strftime()` formatting. Of course, that simplifies things.

Comment: Ya it will be great if you could update your answer with that point. Anyway thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same problem. It uploads the file from the local machine to server
`views.py`

```
def receiveAudioRecord(request):

    if not os.path.exists('recording/wavFiles'):
        os.makedirs('recording/wavFiles')

    if not request.FILES['fileupload']:
        return render(request, "recording.html", {'msg': "Try Again! Unable to upload. </span>"})

    elif request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['fileupload']:
        myfile = request.FILES['fileupload']
        fs = FileSystemStorage("recording/wavFiles")
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)  # saves the file to `media` folder
        fs.url(filename)  # gets the url

        return render(request, "recording.html",{'msg':"successfully uploaded"})
    else:
        return render(request,"recording.html",{'msg':"Try Again! Unable to upload. </span>"})
```